# How can I make jackson to use different views on nested entities of the same type?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Before I start questioning let me give you a simplified example of my case:
Imagine you have `Views`:

```java
public final class Views {
    public interface Id { }

    public interface IdText extends Id { }

    public interface FullProfile extends IdText { }
}
```

You also have a class `User` which has subscribers that are of the same type `User`.
The properties `id` and `username` are serialized in the `Views.IdText.class` view. And the property `subscribers` is serialized in the `Views.FullProfile.class` view.

```java
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @JsonView(Views.IdText.class)
    private Long id;

    @JsonView(Views.IdText.class)
    private String username;

    @JsonIdentityReference
    @JsonIdentityInfo(
            property = "id",
            generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class
    )
    @JsonView(Views.FullProfile.class)
    private Set<User> subscribers = new HashSet<>();
}
```

And a controller (`ProfileController`) that has a method called `get` that returns a user's profile.

```java
@RestController
public class ProfileController {
    
    @GetMapping("{id}")
    @JsonView(Views.FullProfile.class)
    public User get(@PathVariable("id") User user) {
        // ... some service methods that has the necessary logic.
        return user;
    }
    
}
```

As you can see, the method serializes the user's profile in the `Views.FullProfile.class` view, so the output is:

```json
{
  "id": 39,
  "username": "ryan",
  "subscribers": [
    {
      "id": 42,
      "username": "elliott",
      "subscribers": [
        {
          "id": 432,
          "username": "oliver",
          "subscribers": [
            {
              "id": 2525,
              "username": "james",
              "subscribers": [
                39,
                432
              ]
            },
            {
              // ... a lot of useless data goes on.
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 94923,
          "username": "lucas",
          "subscribers": [
            345, 42
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 345,
      "username": "jocko",
      "subscribers": [
        94923
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**When a user's profile is being serialized, I don't need the user's subscribers to be serialized in the `Views.FullProfile.class` view
but in the `Views.IdText.class` view so that the output would be:**

```json
{
  "id": 39,
  "username": "ryan",
  "subscriptions": [
    {
      "id": 42,
      "username": "elliott"
    },
    {
      "id": 345,
      "username": "jocko"
    }
  ]
}
```

**How can I make *jackson* to use different views on nested entities of the same type?
Or what else do I have to do to make that happen?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of continuous searching I found someone issued the same problem on Github: [`@JsonIgnoreProperties` should support nested properties #2940](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2940)
As stated in that issue:

> No plans to ever implement this (due to delegating design, will not be possible with current Jackson architecture), closing.

Comment: I don't know if you considered an alternative approach. but is possible to access the current active view in a custom serializer.